# How to add Scope(Permissions) in Graph API Access Token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used Long-live access token, in this access tiken has default scope such as user_friends, public_profile, basic_info.. i want to add some more scope like emails and more permissions, how to add some more permissions in this access token?

i have attached screenshot for access token details
[image]

Comment: You don't. You pop the login dialog and ask the user for permission. And you will get an access token back that has those permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to request more permissions from your users than put this into your login script:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '{app-id}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
      'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.7',
      ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $permissions = ['email','publish_actions','user_birthday']; // Here you add as much permissions as you like
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://example.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);
```

This will make popup requesting all those permissions to be approved to all new users installing your app. Be aware, because some permissions need to be granted by Facebook in order to use it. You should look more carefully at the docs.

Comment: i didn't try for login concept, i just attempt for simple example, so is there any other way for add scope? i have tried this way `$user = $response->getGraphUser();echo 'Name  : ' . $user->getName();`

Comment: There is no other way for getting any additional Facebook user's info except popping login dialog.